# How to add a textbox to a DWP webart and passing paramters

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer

Not sure if this can be done using OOTB webparts.
I have a list and i want to use webparts to display a master detail view.
But i need a text box in one of the  a webparts so that users can type in an input value and then pass the value to a calculated column to perform some calculation.
Is this possible with OOTB webparts?
I have used OOTB webparts for the view but it seems there is no way to have a textbox with connections.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

From the sounds of it, you'll want to look at Data View Web Parts (DVWPs). By manipulating the XSL in a DVWP, you can do pretty much anything, including creating customized displays and forms.